# Early Draft Map

Tags: internal-consistency, medieval, map-making

I am developing a small (semi fantasy) medieval town and sketched out the basic topography. I sketched layers free-hand on acetates to separate terrain, roads, etc. The areas in boxes are where I see farmland, town and fishing areas ... figures in approximate meters.

It is based on more or less a single valley entrance with sea access.  I want to know whether I have anything wrong with the topography.

Any comments really appreciated.

Skutter

[image]

EDIT - The brown shading is a forest

EDIT - Further to queries on what the question is:

Basically, all I am asking is whether or not the topography in the draft map actually makes sense or if I am making any fundamental errors.  I intend to build the town(s) around the geography so I just want to get the basics right.

Thanks for the comments so far.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Skutter*! You might be interested in some of the questions already on the site such as [Designing a map for a fictional city](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2595/28789) and in general the [Creating a realistic world Series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2595/28789). Currently your post looks like an invitation for open-ended discussions and general feedback. On StackExchange we don't do this sort of forum threads. Is there a single aspect you specifically need an answer to? Please [edit], take the [tour] and visit the [help] for info.

Comment: Since you are creating this map from scratch why don't you give this town a natural port? That could come in very handy for economic development.

Comment: I don't understand what would form the lake with hills to the sides.  That would be an unusual feature geologically.  General thought - establish the forces that form the geography first. Subduction/tectonics/volcanism/erosion/etc. Easier to consider whether something is realistic if you understand the forces that created the landscape.

Comment: Sorry Secespitus, I was just asking for general comments on plausibility rather than a general discussion - wasn't intending to do iterations.

Comment: thanks Alex - read your post after the ones below so think a port to the right may be a better solution

Comment: DPT I wasn't sure about the geology of the lake but I thought that the hook shape (I'm assuming volcanic rock outcrops/vents) would have effectively created a sudden slowing and turning back of the water creating a deeper area clearing out between the outcrops.  Not sure if the two outcrops are split from one or if they formed that way - I will see if I can find similar in a real setting.

Comment: It isn't worth of an answer but those smaller hills next to the lake look like a really good defensive location, so if the town is of strategic importance you would have fortifications there at least so invaders don't get that position to attack the main town. how does it have an impact on your map ? the forest would have been maybe cleared out for better visibility, so I believe the forest is a bit to close from the two hills. but the map is otherwise good to me

Comment: A little tip: to ping users you have to write an "@" in front of their username. It even autocompletes. You can ping one user per comment and the OP of a post is always notified. Your question is currently on hold. By [edit]ing it your question automatically goes into a reopen review queue where people look whether your question is now in accordance with the guidelines listed in the [help]. There is no need for explicit edit notices in the post - everyone can access the revision history. I think by clearing the wording your question might get reopened.

Comment: @Skutter while we can try our best to help you with map questions, if you only need feedback you might be better helped at [the Cartographers Guild](https://cartographersguild.com) - the folks over there tend to do things that I can only explain with magic

Comment: Only thing I can really comment on is the roads, these should really be put in after the towns. Roads generally pop up between civilisation and resources, thats it; though I suppose towns/villages also pop up where roads meet, so you can look at it both ways. A road beside the river probably wont be well mentained do to lack of use, atleast by the richer populous.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of an unanswerable question but wth,

1) in a medieval town why would fishing be zoned? Usually people fish wherever they feel like. Commercial fishing would lead to ports which is where towns would crop up. In this map I like the placement of your town however fishing would be going on in the stream and coastline which would also make for a nice harbor.

In other words, towns dont make industry, industry makes towns.

2) You have what looks like a mountain followed by a quick transition into flatland for farming and then coastline. Normally, that terrain is to uneven for farming and better suited for animal husbandry. The area you zoned for fishing, being between 2 mountains would more reasonably be level enough for farming.

EDIT:

3) I'd like to add, instead of the fishing industrial zone, what you would more likely see is a logging industrial zone. As the town grows from the fishing and farming, the need for building material would increase. There would probably be a satellite wood harvesting community north of the lake and hills but on the stream so they could float supplies into town.

Comment: The first point is valid but I'm not sure about the second: I think that's just a hill, not a mountain. That land looks okay for farming to me. I don't think this is a downvote-able answer, though, curious why this was downvoted.

Comment: Thanks for the comments ... take the point re the fishing - think I had envisioned the town to be more industrial with the fishing part being more an area more suitable for boats which has had  grown up a bit of fishing specific industry (repairs; curing) with a little bit of a small village type set up growing around it.

Comment: Oops - apparently it doesn't like the return key in comments.  It may make more sense to move the bigger harbour nearer the river mouth and leave the fishing area as is.  BTW no idea about the downvote (wouldn't even let me upvote as I have less than 15)

Comment: "..stream and coastline which would also make for a nice harbor." what i meant by this was harbors tend to form where rivers meet large bodies of water because erosion makes them deep enough.

Comment: Medieval towns did have zoning laws especially for stinky industries such as processing fish.

Comment: yeah but most were never built before their fisheries. What usually happened was a fishing village grew from the profitability of their fishing and later zoned off the fishing and residential areas, but they were still co-located. They never said "alright guys, you gotta move your port X miles out of town".